# How to Combine iTunes accounts

Tags: itunes, macos

We have two Mac computers running iTunes, mine and hers.

I sync my peripherals to my MacBook Air and my iTunes account, while she syncs her peripherals with our home iMac. Historically, we each maintained separate Apple IDs and iTunes accounts.

My computer belongs to my former company and is going away, so going forward, "sharing" will not be an option.

- How do I move my music over to the family iMac?
- How do I avoid creating duplicates on the family iMac?
- Is there a way to eliminate multiple duplicates? (the one at a time fix will take forever)
- Is there any other advice?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you create an additional user account for yourself on the family Mac. Of course this will lead to having two copies of specific tracks and apps on the disk but overall it's much easier to handle than trying to combine two accounts (or handle two Apple IDs/ITS accounts from within one iTunes configuration).

For additional information concerning the migration see

- [iTunes: How to move your music to a new computer](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4527)
- [How can I switch the computer I sync my iPhone with and keep my apps?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2498298)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow exactly how to do this. If I migrate over to the family Mac will the library names conflict, causing one to overwrite the other?

Comment: Not if you create a new user account **on the iMac** for yourself (Preferences -> Users & Groups)